# FFmpeg создание скриншотов во время записи

Tags: ffmpeg

Идет запись видео с помощью FFmpeg. Пользователь захотел создать скриншот в один из моментов при нажатии кнопки. Какая команда или как создать скриншот во время записи видео?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg -ss {time}.01 -i {videopath} -y -f image2 -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 {screenpath}"
```

Comment: и как это выполнять если до этого было выполнена к примеру `ffmpeg -i udp://@239.239.2.1:1234 -vcodec copy -an -r 25 -t
time_in_seconds -pix_fmt yuv420p -f mp4 path_for_save_video.mp4` ?

Comment: @Insider а в чем у вас проблема возникла?

Comment: если стрим допустим запущен http://prntscr.com/9xl5qx или идет записать видео, почти таким-же методом. Я ведь никак скриншоты в этот момент не сделаю?

Comment: То есть вы хотите получить скриншот из потока данных?

Comment: Да, именно так, мне нужно получить скриншот во время записи.

Comment: На сколько я знаю, средствами ffmpeg'a это не реализуемо. Т.к. во время записи необходимая нам информация находитя в буффере, к которому нельзя просто так взять и обратиться, т.е. де-факто для этого нужно вклиниться в другой процесс. К файлу в который записывается тоже не получится, т.к. он будет занят записью.

Comment: А что если запустить еще одну инстанцию FFmpeg на той же секунде и заснять все это.

Comment: @Insider так я же выше написал, что вы не можете из другого процесса вмешаться.

Comment: хм, а есть идет udp стрим, запись из него, тогда ведь можно подключится и сделать скриншот?

Comment: Со стрима может получится, попробуйте `ffmpeg -i 'udp://<IP:port>' -r 0.2 -f image2 'framegrab%02d.jpg'`

Comment: У тебя же на малинке он вещает в мультикаст группу? Ты, вроде, так настраивал, не? Тогда да, в любой момент времени ты можешь подклчиться к группе новым инстансом и взять от туда кадр. Другое дело, что это будет... ну не совсем тот же самый момент, в который пользователь нажал кнопку "сделать скрин".

Comment: @MonahTuk вот-вот, я и думаю про задержку. В этом то и будет скорее всего вся проблема. С raspivid или raspistill я не могу захватить, ибо приложение можно запустить только один раз.

Comment: @Insider ну эт костыльный вариант на самом деле, без задержки не выйдет к сожалению.